# get value from another controller angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rootscope

I have problem. I want to pass get from rootScope.reslogin2 to scope.user but it wont display here is my js file

```
    app.controller("logincont", ['$scope','$http','md5','$window','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,md5,$window,$rootScope){
     $scope.$watch('pass', function(val) {
          $scope.password = md5.createHash($scope.pass || '');
        });
    $scope.cari = function () {
            $http.get('http://localhost:8089/MonitoringAPI/webresources/login?a='+$scope.userid+'&d='+$scope.password).then(function(response){
           $scope.reslogin  = response.data;
           $rootScope.reslogin2 = response.data[0].username;
           $scope.reslogin3 = response.data[0].lsmenu[0].idmenu; 
           console.log($scope.reslogin);
           console.log($scope.reslogin2);
      });
          };   

          }]);


    app.controller("moncont", ['$scope','$http','$filter','$rootScope',function($scope,$http,$filter,$rootScope){
      $scope.user = $rootScope.reslogin2;
      console.log($scope.user);
}]);
```

i want to display in this paragraph `<p>Username : {{user}}</p>`

Comment: what do you get in the console?

Comment: undefined @Sunil Lama

Comment: find the answer below see if that helps

Comment: andika perhaps your data from the api is not being assigned at all. can you see what is being logged at `$scope.cari` function.

Comment: $scope.cari is for ng-click. so when button click, it will execute $scope.cari

Comment: whats in the log of $scope.reslogin2

Comment: username of the response

Comment: Are these controllers used in same view? Why isn't there a service wiring all this together?

Comment: @AndikaRistianNugraha, you can use factory in angularjs.  refer this link it will help ful to you             https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory

Answer (score 0):

Make sure value is assigned before accessing it.
In moncont controller keep $rootScope.reslogin2 in watch and assign it to $scope.user in watch function.

Answer (score 0):

`user` from *moncont* controller not synchronized with desired value, so to fix it, you can for example, instead of `$scope.user = $rootScope.reslogin2;` declare corresponding getter via `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('logincont', function($rootScope, $scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.cari = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $rootScope.reslogin2 = ($rootScope.reslogin2 || 0) + 1;
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
  .controller('moncont', function($rootScope, $scope) {
    Object.defineProperty($scope, "user", {
      get: function() {
        return $rootScope.reslogin2
      }
    });
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='logincont'>
    <button ng-click='cari()'>Cari</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller='moncont'>
    user: {{user}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following method in your controller.

```
$scope.init = function(){
   $scope.user = $rootScope.reslogin2;
   console.log($scope.user);
}
```

Your template should be like following:

```
<div ng-controller="moncont" ng-init="init()">
    <p>Username : {{user}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you give plunk or fiddle? @Syedur

Comment: I have updated the code. Can you please try with this?

Comment: i have try it, but it still undefined

Comment: That is **not** what `ng-init` should be used for.